# embed redtube video not playing on iphone/ipad

Tags: html, embed

I am unable to get a redtube video to play on iphone and ipads , here is my embed code , and unfortunately the site i am loading onto will not permit the HTML5 video tags. So is the anyway to have the vid play otherwise ?

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=923961&autostart=1&amp;style=redtube" width="935" height="567">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="id=923961&amp;style=redtube">
    <param name="movie" value="http://embed.redtube.com/player/?id=923961&amp;style=redtube">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

**Warning** to anyone that doesn't know and tries this code out to help debug - RedTube is a porn site.

Comment: Why are you unable to use HTML5 video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh, I just re-read this issue. iPhone/iPad will not play Flash videos. (See: http://www.apple.com/ca/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/)  You will have to use HTML5 video tags if you want this to work.

*Note*: If the site you are uploading to will not allow HTML5 Video tags you might be able to use an iframe (which loads from another site that does allow video tags).  Though as @Drahcir asks, I'm curious why they may be blocking the HTML5 video tags?